# How do I add the MathWorks logo to an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I had asked in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526898/how-do-i-reproduce-this-heart-shaped-mesh-in-matlab) about how to reproduce [an image](http://zedomax.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/i-love-math.jpg) in MATLAB. Now, I want to modify that image by removing the word "Math" and replacing it with the [MathWorks logo](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/shipping/matlab/logo_01.png).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the logo to the figure and adjust its position.

Here's the code I have been trying to use to add the logo to the figure:

```
L = 40*membrane(1,25);

logoFig = figure('Color',[1 1 1]);
logoax = axes('CameraPosition', [80.5 50 42.5],...
    'CameraTarget',[26 26 10], ...
    'CameraUpVector',[0 0 1], ...
    'CameraViewAngle',9.5, ...
    'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 .9],...
    'Position',[0 0 1 1], ...
    'Visible','off', ...
    'XLim',[1 51], ...
    'YLim',[1 51], ...
    'ZLim',[-13 40], ...
    'parent',logoFig);
s = surface(L, ...
    'EdgeColor','none', ...
    'FaceColor',[0.9 0.2 0.2], ...
    'FaceLighting','phong', ...
    'AmbientStrength',0.3, ...
    'DiffuseStrength',0.6, ...
    'Clipping','off',...
    'BackFaceLighting','lit', ...
    'SpecularStrength',1.1, ...
    'SpecularColorReflectance',1, ...
    'SpecularExponent',7, ...
    'Tag','TheMathWorksLogo', ...
    'parent',logoax);
l1 = light('Position',[40 100 20], ...
    'Style','local', ...
    'Color',[0 0.8 0.8], ...
    'parent',logoax);
l2 = light('Position',[.5 -1 .4], ...
    'Color',[0.8 0.8 0], ...
    'parent',logoax);

%http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/logo.html
```

Comment: @izzat: I'm reluctant to help you any more since it's likely you're just going to delete this question after you get your answer, like you have done before. The point of Stack Overflow is not just to answer *your* questions, but to create a repository of programming help for *others* to use as well. Why should I put significant effort into posting an answer if you're going to be selfish and not let anyone else read it?

Comment: i order to set the 'position' i have to 'see' where to put the desired figure i want to put. how can i 'see'?

Comment: when i tried it still many figures came out...

Comment: i promise i will well behaved...

Comment: @gnovice: exactly how I feel..

Comment: @izzat: Alright, I'll give you *one chance* to redeem yourself. *But be warned...* if I put time and effort into answering your question and you immediately delete it, I'm going to boycott everything you post on here from now until time stops! =P

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be having a lot of trouble figuring this out. Here's the image I assume you want to generate:

[image]

First, I started with the functions `heart` and `I_Heart_Math` that I posted in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526898/matlab-and-plot/1589735#1589735) (which use [arrow.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m) and [myaa.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979-myaa-my-anti-alias-for-matlab) from [The MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)). I removed all the code in `I_Heart_Math` that was related to plotting the word "Math" and reduced the size of the figure window.

Next I had to generate and plot the MATLAB L-shaped membrane logo. In MATLAB you can type `logo` and it will open a new figure with the logo displayed on a black background. You can look at the code that generates the figure by typing `type logo` in MATLAB, or you can look at [this MathWorks demo page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/logo.html).

The `logo` code required a few modifications. Since I wanted to add the logo to an already existing figure window, I removed the code that created a new figure window. I changed a few properties for the logo axes as well: the ['Parent' property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#Parent) was set to the current figure window ([GCF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/gcf.html)), the ['Units' property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#Units) was set to 'pixels', and the ['Position' property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#Position) was changed to position the logo axes next to the heart axes within the figure window.

Putting it all together, here's the new `I_Heart_MATLAB` code to generate the above image:

```
function I_Heart_MATLAB

  % Initialize heart plot and adjust figure and axes settings:

  heart;
  set(gcf,'Position',[200 200 640 300],'Name','Original image');
  offset = get(gca,'CameraPosition')-get(gca,'CameraTarget');
  offset = 35.*offset./norm(offset);
  set(gca,'Position',[65 -9 300 300],'CameraViewAngle',6,...
      'XLim',[21+offset(1) 70],'YLim',[16+offset(2) 63],...
      'ZLim',[32 81+offset(3)]);

  % Create the axes and labels, offsetting them in front of the
  % heart to give the appearance they are passing through it:

  arrowStarts = [81 51 51; 51 86 51; 51 51 32]+repmat(offset,3,1);
  arrowEnds = [21 51 51; 51 16 51; 51 51 81]+repmat(offset,3,1);
  arrow(arrowStarts,arrowEnds,5,40,40);
  text('Position',[22 52 48]+offset,'String','x','FontSize',12);
  text('Position',[50 17 49]+offset,'String','y','FontSize',12);
  text('Position',[46.5 51 81.5]+offset,'String','z','FontSize',12);

  % Create the equation text:

  text('Position',[51 47 28],'FontName','Bookman','FontSize',8,...
       'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
       'String',{'(x^2+^9/_4y^2+z^2-1)^3-x^2z^3-^9/_{80}y^2z^3=0'; ...
                 '-3 \leq x,y,z \leq 3'});

  % Create the large-type text:

  hI = text('Position',[4 52 69.5],'String','I',...
            'FontAngle','italic','FontName','Trebuchet MS',...
            'FontSize',116,'FontWeight','bold');

  % Create and plot the L-shaped membrane logo:

  logoData = 40*membrane(1,25);
  logoAxes = axes('Parent',gcf,'Units','pixels',...
                  'Position',[335 21 280 280],...
                  'CameraPosition', [-193.4013 -265.1546  220.4819],...
                  'CameraTarget',[26 26 10],'CameraUpVector',[0 0 1],...
                  'CameraViewAngle',9.5,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 .9],...
                  'XLim',[1 51],'YLim',[1 51],'ZLim',[-13 40],...
                  'Visible','off');
  surface(logoData,'Parent',logoAxes,'EdgeColor','none',...
          'FaceColor',[0.9 0.2 0.2],'FaceLighting','phong',...
          'AmbientStrength',0.3,'DiffuseStrength',0.6,...
          'Clipping','off','BackFaceLighting','lit',...
          'SpecularStrength',1.1,'SpecularColorReflectance',1,...
          'SpecularExponent',7);
  light('Parent',logoAxes,'Position',[40 100 20],'Color',[0 0.8 0.8],...
        'Style','local');
  light('Parent',logoAxes,'Position',[.5 -1 .4],'Color',[0.8 0.8 0]);

  % Create an anti-aliased version of the figure too (the larger
  % fonts need some adjustment to do this... not sure why):

  set(hI,'FontSize',86);
  myaa;
  set(hI,'FontSize',116);
  set(gcf,'Name','Anti-aliased image');

end
```

Comment: how to define the 'position'? is it depends on coordinate or gridline or something? still blur???