# Plotting implicit equations in 3d

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'd like to plot implicit equation F(x,y,z) = 0 in 3D. Is it possible in Matplotlib?

Comment: You can find some examples at: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/index.html

Comment: Do you need to do it with matplotlib?  If not, you might want to have a look at [3d contour plots in Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#enthought.mayavi.mlab.contour3d).

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Thank You, but unfortunately I have to do it with Matplotlib.

Comment: It looks good except you aren't shifting the location of the z contour by the value of z.  They all get plotted at 0.0!  Plus you need to manually define the plotted limits since the z contour solution will extend way beyond your desired contour interval.

Comment: I've updated my post with cleaner code that includes plotted contour intervals (slices) along other axes.

Comment: When I cleaned up my code, I decided to rename X, Y, Z, x, y, and z to make it very clear what is going on.  This may have caused more confusion than it solved!  Look closely at your `for` loops (mainly the second two) and make sure they match my example.  You need to either swap all your X, Y, Z, x, y, and z's like I did, or you need to delete the lines that look like: `X,Z= A1, A2`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can trick matplotlib into plotting implicit equations in 3D.  Just make a one-level contour plot of the equation for each z value within the desired limits.  You can repeat the process along the y and z axes as well for a more solid-looking shape.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_implicit(fn, bbox=(-2.5,2.5)):
    ''' create a plot of an implicit function
    fn  ...implicit function (plot where fn==0)
    bbox ..the x,y,and z limits of plotted interval'''
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax = bbox*3
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    A = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # resolution of the contour
    B = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 15) # number of slices
    A1,A2 = np.meshgrid(A,A) # grid on which the contour is plotted

    for z in B: # plot contours in the XY plane
        X,Y = A1,A2
        Z = fn(X,Y,z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z+z, [z], zdir='z')
        # [z] defines the only level to plot for this contour for this value of z

    for y in B: # plot contours in the XZ plane
        X,Z = A1,A2
        Y = fn(X,y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y+y, Z, [y], zdir='y')

    for x in B: # plot contours in the YZ plane
        Y,Z = A1,A2
        X = fn(x,Y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X+x, Y, Z, [x], zdir='x')

    # must set plot limits because the contour will likely extend
    # way beyond the displayed level.  Otherwise matplotlib extends the plot limits
    # to encompass all values in the contour.
    ax.set_zlim3d(zmin,zmax)
    ax.set_xlim3d(xmin,xmax)
    ax.set_ylim3d(ymin,ymax)

    plt.show()
```

Here's the plot of the Goursat Tangle:

```
def goursat_tangle(x,y,z):
    a,b,c = 0.0,-5.0,11.8
    return x**4+y**4+z**4+a*(x**2+y**2+z**2)**2+b*(x**2+y**2+z**2)+c

plot_implicit(goursat_tangle)
```

[image]

You can make it easier to visualize by adding depth cues with creative colormapping:

[image]

Here's how the OP's plot looks:

```
def hyp_part1(x,y,z):
    return -(x**2) - (y**2) + (z**2) - 1

plot_implicit(hyp_part1, bbox=(-100.,100.))
```

[image]

Bonus:  You can use python to functionally combine these implicit functions:

```
def sphere(x,y,z):
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 2.0**2

def translate(fn,x,y,z):
    return lambda a,b,c: fn(x-a,y-b,z-c)

def union(*fns):
    return lambda x,y,z: np.min(
        [fn(x,y,z) for fn in fns], 0)

def intersect(*fns):
    return lambda x,y,z: np.max(
        [fn(x,y,z) for fn in fns], 0)

def subtract(fn1, fn2):
    return intersect(fn1, lambda *args:-fn2(*args))

plot_implicit(union(sphere,translate(sphere, 1.,1.,1.)), (-2.,3.))
```

[image]

Comment: @bpowah: According to matplotlib reference  projection = '3d' is invalid.  Perhaps projection = 'rectilinear'?

Comment: I remember getting that error before upgrading to matplotlib 1.0.1.  I forget how to get around it for previous versions.

Comment: @bpowah: Oh, you're using newer matplotlib version. Anyway I'll try to figure this out. Thanks))

Comment: @bpowah: I'm trying to get into your code, but I don't understand how Z = sphere(X,Y,z) works.

Comment: @qutron: Try `ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)`

Comment: @qutron: sphere(X,Y,z) is being given a 2D array of X's and a 2D array of Y's and a single value for z.  It returns a 2D array representing a slice of the surface at z.  It's then up to `contour` to find the where in that array the values are equal to `radius`

Comment: Depending on the version of mplot3d there can appear some difficulties with your code. There are inconsistences in the repo with *args between the 2d and 3d contour plotting functions. Updating to the latest version of mplot3d and change the calls to ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[y], zdir='y') will hopefully help.

Comment: @Paul What is the creative colormapping you are using?

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: @Paul, I like the way you provided surface operations, very pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: I finally have found an easy way to render 3D implicit surface with `matplotlib` and `scikit-image`, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773167/3067485). I left this one for whom is interested in plotting parametric 3D surfaces.

#### Motivation

Late answer, I just needed to do the same and I found another way to do it at some extent. So I am sharing this another perspective.

This post does not answer: (1) How to plot any implicit function `F(x,y,z)=0`? But does answer: (2) How to plot parametric surfaces (not all implicit functions, but some of them) using mesh with `matplotlib`?

@Paul's method has the advantage to be non parametric, therefore we can plot almost anything we want using contour method on each axe, it fully addresses (1). But `matplotlib` cannot easily build a mesh from this method, so we cannot directly get a surface from it, instead we get plane curves in all directions. This is what motivated my answer, I wanted to address (2).

#### Rendering mesh

If we are able to parametrize (this may be hard or impossible), with at most 2 parameters, the surface we want to plot then we can plot it with [`matplotlib.plot_trisurf`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo.html) method.

That is, from an implicit equation `F(x,y,z)=0`, if we are able to get a parametric system `S={x=f(u,v), y=g(u,v), z=h(u,v)}` then we can plot it easily with `matplotlib` without having to resort to `contour`.

Then, rendering such a 3D surface boils down to:

```
# Render:
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap='jet', antialiased=True)
```

Where `(x, y, z)` are vectors (not [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), see [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)) functionally computed from parameters `(u, v)` and `triangles` parameter is a Triangulation derived from `(u,v)` parameters to shoulder the mesh construction.

#### Imports

Required imports are:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
```

#### Some surfaces

Lets parametrize some surfaces...

Sphere

```
# Parameters:
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 20)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
rho = 1

# Parametrization:
x = np.ravel(rho*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi))
y = np.ravel(rho*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi))
z = np.ravel(rho*np.cos(phi))

# Triangulation:
tri = Triangulation(np.ravel(theta), np.ravel(phi))
```

[image]

Cone

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
rho = np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
theta, rho = np.meshgrid(theta, rho)

x = np.ravel(rho*np.cos(theta))
y = np.ravel(rho*np.sin(theta))
z = np.ravel(rho)

tri = Triangulation(np.ravel(theta), np.ravel(rho))
```

[image]

Torus

```
a, c = 1, 4
u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
v = u.copy()
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)

x = np.ravel((c + a*np.cos(v))*np.cos(u))
y = np.ravel((c + a*np.cos(v))*np.sin(u))
z = np.ravel(a*np.sin(v))

tri = Triangulation(np.ravel(u), np.ravel(v))
```

[image]

[Möbius Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)

```
u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
v = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)

x = np.ravel((2 + (v/2)*np.cos(u/2))*np.cos(u))
y = np.ravel((2 + (v/2)*np.cos(u/2))*np.sin(u))
z = np.ravel(v/2*np.sin(u/2))

tri = Triangulation(np.ravel(u), np.ravel(v))
```

[image]

#### Limitation

Most of the time, [`Triangulation`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.html) is required in order to coordinate mesh construction of `plot_trisurf` method, and this object only accepts two parameters, so we are limited to 2D parametric surfaces. It is unlikely we could represent the Goursat Tangle with this method.

Comment: @Paul, I have found a way to represent 2d parametric 3d functions as surface using `tri_surf` and `Triangulation`, do you know it? I am wondering if there is a way to build a valid mesh from your contours.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is an easy way to plot implicit 3D surface with the `scikit-image` package. The key is the [`marching_cubes`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html) method.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
```

Then we compute the function over a 3D meshgrid, in this example we use the `goursat_tangle` method `@Paul` defined in its answer:

```
xl = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(xl, xl, xl)
F = goursat_tangle(X, Y, Z)
```

The magic is happening here with [`marching_cubes`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes):

```
verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes(F, 0, spacing=[np.diff(xl)[0]]*3)
verts -= 3
```

We just need to correct vertices coordinates as they are expressed in [Voxel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) coordinates (hence scaling using `spacing` switch and the subsequent origin shift).

Finally it is just about rendering the iso-surface using [`tri_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(verts[:, 0], verts[:, 1], faces, verts[:, 2], cmap='jet', lw=0)
```

Which returns:

[image]

Comment: @qutron and @Paul, I found an easy way to plot implicit 3D surface with `matplotlib` and `scikit-image`. Cheers

Comment: Had to add `plot.show()` to make it work. I'd also suggest you add the Goursat Tangle or some other function for completeness and consider adding it all together in one code block for easy copy-pasting.

Comment: Great. I think x-axis and y-axis are interchanged. For a non-symmetric function
`ax.plot_trisurf(verts[:, 1], verts[:, 0], faces, verts[:, 2], cmap='jet', lw=0)` suits my expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib expects a series of points; it will do the plotting if you can figure out how to render your equation.

Referring to [Is it possible to plot implicit equations using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527/is-it-possible-to-plot-implicit-equations-using-matplotlib) Mike Graham's answer suggests using scipy.optimize to numerically explore the implicit function.

There is an interesting gallery at http://xrt.wikidot.com/gallery:implicit showing a variety of raytraced implicit functions - if your equation matches one of these, it might give you a better idea what you are looking at.

Failing that, if you care to share the actual equation, maybe someone can suggest an easier approach.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible. You have to solve this equation numerically by yourself. Using scipy.optimize is a good idea. The simplest case is that you know the range of the surface that you want to plot, and just make a regular grid in x and y, and try to solve equation F(xi,yi,z)=0 for z, giving a starting point of z. Following is a very dirty code that might help you

```
from scipy import *
from scipy import optimize

xrange = (0,1)
yrange = (0,1)
density = 100
startz = 1

def F(x,y,z):
    return x**2+y**2+z**2-10

x = linspace(xrange[0],xrange[1],density)
y = linspace(yrange[0],yrange[1],density)

points = []
for xi in x:
    for yi in y:
        g = lambda z:F(xi,yi,z)
        res = optimize.fsolve(g, startz, full_output=1)
        if res[2] == 1:
            zi = res[0]
            points.append([xi,yi,zi])

points = array(points)
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea.  Try F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 to see the problem.  It should plot a sphere, but your code will only plot half a shpere.

Comment: Oh, just noticed you are using basically the same function already :)

Comment: That's true. If implicit function is multi-valued, there is a problem. As I said, it's just a dirty code to make the simplest thing possible.#

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did it (I updated my matplotlib to 1.0.1).
Here is code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def hyp_part1(x,y,z):
    return -(x**2) - (y**2) + (z**2) - 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x_range = np.arange(-100,100,10) 
y_range = np.arange(-100,100,10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x_range,y_range)
A = np.linspace(-100, 100, 15)

A1,A2 = np.meshgrid(A,A)    

for z in A: 
    X,Y = A1, A2
    Z = hyp_part1(X,Y,z)
    ax.contour(X, Y, Z+z, [z], zdir='z')

for y in A: 
    X,Z= A1, A2
    Y = hyp_part1(X,y,Z)
    ax.contour(X, Y+y, Z, [y], zdir='y')

for x in A:
    Y,Z = A1, A2 
    X = hyp_part1(x,Y,Z)
    ax.contour(X+x, Y, Z, [x], zdir='x')

ax.set_zlim3d(-100,100)
ax.set_xlim3d(-100,100)
ax.set_ylim3d(-100,100)
```

Here is result:[image]

Thank You, Paul!

Answer (score 1):

By using the marching_cubes method from the [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) library, the mesh is easily created.  Shading of the surface can then be made using [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), a Matplotlib third party package, to produce:

[image]

where the code to generate the above figure, using the method given in Paul's answer, is:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import marching_cubes_lewiner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

def goursat_tangle(x,y,z):
    a,b,c = 0.0,-5.0,11.8
    return x**4+y**4+z**4+a*(x**2+y**2+z**2)**2+b*(x**2+y**2+z**2)+c

x, y, z = 3*np.mgrid[-1:1:61j, -1:1:61j, -1:1:61j]
vol = goursat_tangle(x,y,z)
verts, faces, _, _ = marching_cubes_lewiner(vol, 0.001, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1))

surface = s3d.Surface3DCollection( verts-3, faces, color='wheat')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
s3d.auto_scale(ax,surface)
ax.set(xlabel='X',ylabel='Y',zlabel='Z')
ax.add_collection3d(surface.shade().hilite(focus=2))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The S3Dlib package also provides the ability to functionally color map surfaces.  If needed, different colors for the 'front' and 'back' surfaces can be used to enhance the surface features, as shown in the following figure:

[image: twist surface]

using the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d
import s3dlib.cmap_utilities as cmu

def twistFunction(rtz) :
    w = rtz[2]/3
    phi = 3*rtz[1]
    R = 1 + w*np.cos(phi)
    Z = w*np.sin(phi)
    return R,rtz[1],Z

bcmap = cmu.binary_cmap('silver', 'sandybrown')
surface = s3d.CylindricalSurface(5, basetype='squ_s', cmap=bcmap)
surface.map_geom_from_op( twistFunction )

minmax=(-1.2,1.2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=minmax, ylim=minmax, zlim=minmax)
ax.view_init(azim=-70)

surface.map_cmap_from_normals(direction=ax)
ax.add_collection3d(surface.shade(ax=ax).hilite(ax=ax))

fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

As an additional note, the S3Dlib documentation contains numerous examples of plotting surfaces from parametric equations.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness it is worth mentioning the straightforward solution: solving the equation in respect to z and plotting it as a function of x, y (note that this requires some idea about how function behaves, to capture all the roots):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import sys

def hyp_part1(x,y,z):
    return -(x**2) - (y**2) + (z**2) - 1


n=500
x_mesh = np.linspace(-100,100,n) 
y_mesh = np.linspace(-100,100,n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)

z = np.array([fsolve(lambda z: hyp_part1(x, y, z), [-1., 1.]) for x, y in zip(X.ravel(), Y.ravel())])
Z1 = z[:,0].reshape(X.shape)
Z2 = z[:,1].reshape(X.shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2)
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]