# How to plot 3D surface for implicit functions in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, plot, 3d

I have the equation:  sqrt(2)*cos(xy) = (z/sqrt(2)) + sin(z) - cos(z) 
with following interval

-1 <= x <= 1  and dx = 0.1

0 <= y <= 1.5  and dx = 0.05

that I need to plot the 3D surface of on excel.

I can't simplify the equation interms of z so how can I calculate the possible values in the matrix form for the given x and y values?

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUoo_7KQfO0 but I don't know how to write the above equation in terms of z.

Comment: You wrote "but I don't know how to write the above equation in terms of z." well that is a Maths question not a VBA question.

Comment: Looks doable in Python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680525/plotting-implicit-equations-in-3d#answer-4687582

Answer (score 0):

First of all your number of values of x/y looks different, x has 20 values, while y has 30
I think it should be

```
-1 <= x <= 1 and dx = 0.1
0 <= y <= 1 and dx = 0.05
```

Or

```
-1 <= x <= 2 and dx = 0.1
0 <= y <= 1.5 and dx = 0.05
```

Then about z, you can find it in excel using Goal Seek

[image]

with formulae
[image]

In above screenshot using Goal Seek you have to find value of (z/sqrt(2)) + sin(z) - cos(z)  (column F) where it is equal to value of sqrt(2)*cos(xy) (column E) by changing the values of Z(column C)

As an example: For first value you would enter like below

[image]

After you have generated all z you can select all the data of x, y and z and insert the 3d surface graph.